# Android : Fix textview in center of LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, button, textview, android-linearlayout

How can i fix my TextView in center of its parent LinearLayout. And a button in the gap b/w TextView & right edge of parent. (TextView must be in center). Please help me.

```
|--------------------------------------------------------|  <------Parent Linearlayout

|                  MyTextviewInCenter          BackButton|  <------There should not be any gap b/w Button & its parent 
|--------------------------------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello"/>

        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Back"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>      

    </RelativeLayout>>


</LinearLayout>
```

You can do like this

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. 
Can't we do the same without using Rel_Layout?

Comment: I think it's not possible with just LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Set the Orientation of Linear Layout horizontal:

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

After that set the gravity of Textview "center"

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

And at last set the left margin of Button what do you want

```
android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
```

I think it may help you...!!!